# Bing predictive search in Chrome doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines, bing

I recently changed my default search engine in Chrome to Bing custom search (http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=%s).

After this, I am not able to use predictive search in Chrome. It seems to work with the Google search that comes by default in Chrome. IS it possible to use this feature with Bing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I switch my search engine to Bing, this is what I get http://i.imgur.com/JBGgmXV.png

Comment: Bing on Chrome? Pretty sure that's like IE on Linux: Might end the world.

Comment: I am using a custom version of Bing Search. Notice the url in the question. Could that be the problem?

Comment: the custom url could be an issue, does bing.com work fine for you ? on a separate note - do you work for Microsoft ?

Comment: No, the default bing.com search isnt working in predictive mode. Google and Quora are working fine. Is this a known problem with Bing. And No, I dont work for Microsoft :)